# display results of query to form::select in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

im pretty new in using this so im stuck where i needed to display the output the result of a certain query as a dropdown in my view. In my controller, here is the query

```
//categories
    $cats  = DB::table('nsa_subcategory AS sc')
             ->join('nsa_maincategory AS mc' , 'sc.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'mc.maincategoryid')
             ->select('sc.subcategoryid' , 'sc.subcategoryname' , 'mc.maincategoryname')
             ->get();
    // dd($cats);
```

i needed to display the `subcategoryname`and `maincategoryname`in the dropdown and get the value of `subcategoryid`im stuck in here. any ideas on how to implement this? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A `foreach` loop in the view that prints out `<option>` tags seems appropriate.

Comment: can you share the output ? the dd() result

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**controller**

```
$cats  = DB::table('nsa_subcategory AS sc')
             ->join('nsa_maincategory AS mc' , 'sc.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'mc.maincategoryid')
             ->select('sc.subcategoryid' , 'sc.subcategoryname' , 'mc.maincategoryname')->lists('id', 'categorie name')
             ; // change this with the right data , the first wil be the value the second will be displayed
```

**View**

```
foreach ($cats as $maincat => $subcat) { 
 echo $subcat;
}
```

**Dropdownlist**

```
{{ Form::select('size', $cats,'Choose category') }}
```

even if dosent work, the essential part is the `->lists()` function, adding that to the query will prepare the data to be diplayed in a dropdown
if you faced any kind of error , Post a comment and i will update the answer if needed

Answer (score 1):

the said query will give you a Collection Object, but what you need instead is an array .. of key=>value pairs. The following should do:

```
$cats  = DB::table('nsa_subcategory AS sc')
         ->join('nsa_maincategory AS mc' , 'sc.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'mc.maincategoryid')
         ->lists(DB::raw('CONCAT(sc.subcategoryname," " , mc.maincategoryname) AS cat_name'),'cat_id');
```

This will give you the desired result. And if you're using Laravel's form helper, you can directly pass it like this:

```
{{Form::select('name',$cats)}}
```

Comment: hi rahul im getting something saying `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: Probably the select function is making trouble.. I'll update the answer accordingly..

Comment: i don't know what is happening but it gives me any error because it uses the query `select `subcategoryname,"` as `,`, `nsa_subcategory`.`subcategoryid` from `nsa_subcategory` inner join `nsa_maincategory` on `nsa_subcategory`.`maincategoryid` = `nsa_maincategory`.`maincategoryid`` which i don't know why it uses that kind of query any ideas?